# How to make a bar plot from data with multiple events in multiple years

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
date     id         freq
6/17/12 0417D0214D   81
6/17/12 0417D2F96C  275
6/18/12 04179385A3    1
6/18/12 041793A84F    2
6/18/12 0417CA9138    2
6/18/12 0417D0214D  120
```

How can I make a stacked bar plot with date on the x axis and frequency on the y axis and the different ids stacked for each date shown with relative size and different colors?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a lot to work with being only one category but here goes:

```
 dat <- read.table(text="date     id         freq
 6/17/12 0417D0214D   81
 6/17/12 0417D2F96C  275
 6/18/12 04179385A3    1
 6/18/12 041793A84F    2
 6/18/12 0417CA9138    2
 6/18/12 0417D0214D  120", header=TRUE)


 barplot(as.matrix(dat$freq) , beside=FALSE)
```